# codeigniter upload an image file error

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, file-upload, multipartform-data

please help me with this error. I have a javascript that i want to append a single image file to my form and i want to send the form data into ajax.

Here is my code:

```
<form id="frm_product" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div style="position:relative;">                    
            <input type="file" name="addfiles" id="addfiles">
        <span class='label label-info' id="upload-file-info"></span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="cat_name">Product Name: </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="prod_name">
        <span class="error prod_name"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="cat_desc">Description: </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="prod_desc">
        <span class="error prod_desc"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="cat_desc">Price: </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="prod_price">
        <span class="error prod_price"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="cat_desc">Category: </label>
        <select class="form-control" name="prod_cat">
          <?php foreach($data as $category){ ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $category->id; ?>"><?php echo $category->name; ?></option>';
          <?php } ?>  
        </select>
        <span class="error prod_cat"></span>
    </div>
</form>
```

here is my ajax code where i want to append a single file:

```
function submitProduct() {
      var formData = new FormData($("#frm_product")[0]);
      formData.append('image', $("#addfiles")[0].files);

         $.ajax({
          url : siteurl+"/product/addproduct",
          type: "POST",
          data: formData,
          dataType: "JSON",
          contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
          processData: false,
          contentType: false,
          cache: false,
              success: function(resp) {                    
                    $('.error').html('');
                    if(resp.status == false) {
                      $.each(resp.message,function(i,m){
                          $('.'+i).text(m);
                      });                      
                    }
                    else if(resp.status == true) {
                      $('#addProduct').modal('hide');
                      $('#frm_product')[0].reset();                      
                      alert("Successfully Added");                     
                    }
                }
       });
    }
```

when i do upload file it says error:

you didn't select a file to upload

Comment: what about `$("#addfiles")[0].files[0]`?

Comment: @sintakonte is that the syntax? i dont really know

Comment: @sintakonte thanks.. you solve my question

Comment: it was just a metaphoric question mark - yeah thats the correct syntax - glad to help ;)